# Not getting cacheparams under rowdata in ag-grid-react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am working on ag-grid-react and in that I am using a existingframework model. I need to get gridApi.rowModel. cacheparam.sortModel value.But when I am debugging cacheparam is not present in gridApi.rowMdel. and throwing uncaught type error.Please help on this.

It should come automatically on gridready,but not getting cacheparam in rowmodel.I am using ^23.2.1 version of ag-grid-react